# double inverted( " " ) after charAt()

Tags: java, string

what is the use of double inverted( "" ) after charAt()?

```
String charToRemove = commonChars.charAt(i)+"";
```

Comment: Try `String charToRemove = commonChars.charAt(i);`, without the `...+""`, and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes after a char allows to convert char to string object

Answer (score 1):

`charToRemove` is a `String` variable but `charAt()` returns `char` type variable. To store `char` variable to string concate operator `+` is used which takes any variable type and return `String`.

Answer (score 0):

It converts the character into String. The String.charAt(...) method returns a character. It cannot be assigned to a String object (charToRemove). Hence a quick hack is done to convert the character to a String by appending an empty string to the end of the returned Character.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `""` implicitly converts the `char` type that is returned from the method `charAt(int)` into a `String` type, which can be stored in a `String` object. By default, Java does not allow implicit conversions from `char` to String, so this is a requirement. This is not the only way to do it though, as you can also use `String.valueOf(char)` or some other methods that can help convert `char` type to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a *trick* for coercing the value to a `String`.

The expression to the right of the `=` assignment operator has the same effect as all of the following:

```java
"" + commonChars.charAt(i)

new StringBuilder().append(commonChars.charAt(i)).append("").toString()

Character.toString(commonChars.charAt(i))

String.valueOf(commonChars.charAt(i))

commonChars.substring(i, i + 1)
```

The second one is actually the same as what the compiler generates in bytecode from the expression in the question.

Personally, I dislike using that trick, but some people use it because it is the shortest/simplest way to do it. I'd have gone with the `substring()` version myself, but if you decide to use `""` trick, place it in the beginning, like shown in the first example above, since that allows concatenating multiple values together.